# ProtoInclude adds unwanted dependencies

Tags: protobuf-net

I just replaced .NET serialization with protocol buffers in a distributed cache application and the results are really impressive. The only thing I do not like is the fact that I need to add dependencies between a base message class and its children which creates a circular dependency. Is there an alternative to tagging base class with ProtoInclude?

Answer (score 5):

In v1; `[ProtoInclude]` is the only way to support inheritance.

In v2, you can use `MetaType`'s `.AddSubType(...)` method to achieve the same thing, without requiring your base-type to know about the derived type(s).