# Limiting protobuf-net inheritance "tree"

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Going on with my quest to bend protobuf-net to my own will..

I've seen a few questions around SO on how to add sub-classes dynamically
for the serializer to be able to encode the sub-class.., like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247513/protobuf-net-inheritance) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231789/protoinclude-adds-unwanted-dependencies)

My situation is bit different, I have a base class that might get sub-classed in late-bounded code, and I want to serialize is as the BASE class, and completely ignore the sub-class's fields/properties.

The reason I need this, is that later on, when I deserialize the data, the sub-class's code will not be even available, so constructing the sub-class will not be even possible.

Is there a way to limit/prohibit sub-class serializtion?

In my case I have a List where some items in the list are DerivedClass.

I would like to find a way to make protobuf-net serialize everything as BaseClass and to deserialize to BaseClass as well...

I've tried peering into code, but haven't found something too useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the library is very particular about spotting derived classes - and treating them differently from the base class. The only *current* exception to that is proxy classes, in particular Entity Framework and NHibernate. For a *tidy* solution, it would seem practical to add some kind of "ignore subclasses" switch. But while that doesn't exist, a *very lazy* (and hacky) approach would be to cheat using the existing handling for NHibernate, for example:

```
namespace NHibernate.Proxy {
    interface INHibernateProxy {}
}
...
public class SomeDerivedType : BaseType, INHibernateProxy {}
```

this will then automatically be serialized as per `BaseType`. It does have a faint whiff of cheating about it, though.

Comment: Faint whiff you say? ;) I think I'll hack into the source Coe but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @damageboy if you wanted to add some custom mechanism for this, `TypeModel.ResolveProxies` would be worth looking at. I'm not against adding a protobuf-net specific API here.

Comment: Just so we are in the clear here... The reason you are pointing me towards ResolveProxies is because it is called from ThrowUnexpectedSubtype as last resort before throwing the exception?

Comment: @damageboy there are, IIRC, a *number* of places (not just `ThrowUnexpectedSubtype`) that use that method as a second-chance - most importantly `TypeModel.GetKey` (which is how it chooses a strategy from a `Type`) and `FindOrAddAuto` / `FindWithoutAdd`.

Comment: Hi Marc, I ended up adding a property on the MetaType: "FlattenUnexpectedSubtypes" which ultimately changes the code generator's emitted IL according to the presence of this flag... Seems to work fine... I've tried sending you a patch a couple of days ago for some other feature but didn't get any response from you... if e-mail a preferred method of communicating for patches?

Comment: @damageboy no offence was intended; my inbox is a wild and dangerous place... I'll check later

Comment: @MarcGravell Did this ever get patched in? I need this functionality.

Comment: @MarcGravell Did this ever make it in somewhere? Or is there a new way to do this in v2?